# How can I download protected Google Drive pdf as .jpg images with browser console?

Tags: javascript, json

I know that there is a script that allows me to download the file as *.pdf using `jspdf` (see below), but the final file is heavy with a bad quality. Instead I would like to download protected *.pdf as a bunch of *.jpg images (one per page) and then merge them with adobe acrobat in order to get a better resolution and a lighter file.

Is this possible using a script in the browser console?

The script I was talking about is this (found in internet):

```
let jspdf = document.createElement("script");
 
jspdf.onload = function () {
    let pdf = new jsPDF();
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (let i in elements) {
        let img = elements[i];
        console.log("add img ", img);
        if (!/^blob:/.test(img.src)) {
            console.log("invalid src");
            continue;
        }
        let can = document.createElement('canvas');
        let con = can.getContext("2d");
        can.width = img.width;
        can.height = img.height;
        con.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        let imgData = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
        pdf.addPage();
    }
 
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
};
 
jspdf.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js';
document.body.appendChild(jspdf);
```

Is there a way to edit this script to get a .jpg for every document's page (maybe zipped using zip.js or JSZip - I was suggested)?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

PS: I don't know a lot about programming, so please explain as throughouly as possible!

Comment: At least in theory, a PDF should be "higher quality" and have a smaller file size (due to vector graphics) than a bitmap based image. It seems unlikely you will get better results after converting the file.

Comment: I know, because I tried it, that downloading the file as .jpg images and then creating a .pdf with adobe Acrobat gets me a better file than using JSPdf (better in quality and dimension).